# How to move an image horozontally in UWP with C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am transitioning from Windows forms to UWP, and as an exercise want to move an image across the screen. In Forms its easy using image.Left, but for the life of me I can't find a way in UWP.

I tried wrapping it in Canvas, as suggested elsewhere,

```
 <Canvas
        x:Name="cDog1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="29,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image
            x:Name="Dog1"
            Canvas.Left="0"
            Source="Assets/images/dog.png"
            Stretch="None" />
    </Canvas>
```

But still can't get back a Canvas.Left that can be changed.
In the materials I read they speak of a SetLeft, yet that isn't an option.

Solved!

```
 <Canvas
        x:Name="cDog1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="29,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image
            x:Name="Dog1"
            Canvas.Left="0"
            Source="Assets/images/dog.png"
            Stretch="None" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="MoveDog1" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
```

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ed8bbf8-5a63-4ef9-a9e5-ddcb310ed865/uwpchow-do-i-move-something-with-a-button-press?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I solved it!!! https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ed8bbf8-5a63-4ef9-a9e5-ddcb310ed865/uwpchow-do-i-move-something-with-a-button-press?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Don't put the answer into the question. Instead, post it as a separate answer. This makes the question easily identifiable as answered, both for humans and machines. And it allows others to vote on it. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the help center.